# Is KL divergence between two discrete pdfs minimized when they are closest in Euclidean distance?

Tags: probability, optimization, information-theory, entropy

I've been wondering about a simple question for few minutes, but I can't find any relevant questions or references by googling.

I want to minimize KL divergence from $p\in \Delta(A)$ where A is some discrete set to compact set $\Theta\subset \Delta(A)$ where $p \notin \Theta$. That is, I want to solve
$$\min_{q\in\Theta}D(p||q)$$
Since $A$ is a discrete set, $\Theta, \Delta(A)$ is just a subset of $\mathbb{R}^{|A|}$.

Intuitively, since KL divergence measures "distance", I've conjectured that this would be minimized with $q$ closest to $p$ in Euclidean distance.

I'm not sure if I can prove it, or even if it is right at all. Does the following hold?

$$arg\min_{q\in\Theta}D(p||q)=arg\min_{q\in\Theta}d(p,q)$$
$d(p,q)$ is the standard Euclidean metric.

Any answers/counter examples/references would be helpful. Thank you!

Comment: KL divergence is not even s distance. Unlike Euclidean Distance, it does not satisfy the triangle inequality, and is not symmetric  with respect to its arguments.

Comment: If you define your 'Euclidean Distance' as $\sum_{i}^{} (p_i-q_i)^2$, then yes. Both achieve minimum when distributions are equal.

Answer (score 1):

What you are doing here is essentially an [information projection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Information_projection). Your conjecture would thus mean that information projection is equivalent to an $\ell_2$-projection.

There is no reason why this should be the case. Take the following example:

Suppose we want to project $p= [\frac12, \frac16, \frac13]$ onto the family of distributions $\Theta = \{q_{\theta} = [\theta, \frac12-\theta, \frac12]: \theta \in (0, 1/2) \}$.

If you try to compute the corresponding projections, you will find that (solved numerically):

- $\min_{q \in \Theta}D(p\|q) = \min_{\theta \in (0, \frac12)} D(p\| q_\theta) \approx 0.0566$ is attained at $\theta =\frac38$ (check [here](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=minimize%20%280.5*log%28%5Cfrac%7B1%7D%7B%5Cleft%282x%5Cright%29%7D%5Cright%29%2B%5Cleft%28%5Cfrac%7B1%7D%7B6%7D%5Cright%29%5Ccdot%5Clog%5Cleft%28%5Cfrac%7B1%7D%7B6%5Cleft%280.5-x%5Cright%29%7D%5Cright%29%2B%5Cleft%28%5Cfrac%7B1%7D%7B3%7D%5Cright%29%5Ccdot%5Clog%5Cleft%28%5Cfrac%7B2%7D%7B3%7D%29%29)).
- $\min_{q \in \Theta}\|p-q\|_2 = \min_{\theta \in (0, \frac12)}  = \min_{\theta \in (0, \frac12)} \|p-q_\theta\|_2 \approx 0.2041$ is attained at $\theta = \frac{5}{12}$ (check [here](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=minimize%20%5Csqrt%7B%5Cleft%28%5Cfrac%7B1%7D%7B2%7D-x%5Cright%29%5E%7B2%7D%2B%5Cleft%28%5Cfrac%7B1%7D%7B6%7D-%5Cleft%28%5Cfrac%7B1%7D%7B2%7D-x%5Cright%29%5Cright%29%5E%7B2%7D%2B%5Cleft%28%5Cfrac%7B1%7D%7B3%7D-0.5%5Cright%29%5E%7B2%7D%7D)).